# How do I change elements of a target page following a window.open()?

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I am creating a button that upon click will open a new window with webpage X, within which there is a search bar that needs to automatically reflect the search "Team."

I already have the `document.getElementById()` of webpage X, and my button already opens webpage X, but how do I (upon window.open) fill the search bar with "Team" using a script that is being run on the first page.

I hope this is clear, as I am somewhat new to this.

Comment: what do you mean by 'reflect the search'? It's also unclear what 'fill the seachbar' means

Comment: Also are you 100% sure you are talking about Java, not JavaScript? They are completely different technologies despite similarities in their names.

Comment: @secretwpn that's true, but he might be using `jsp`... however, OP said 'Writing in java'

Comment: He may be confused... It's clearly talking about Javascript, as he uses its functions, it's manipulating DOM by means of the document object and he says that a "script" is being run...

Comment: Hey sorry for being confusing. I am using Javascript and manipulating DOM

Comment: Aleks, please see the edit to my answer. And don't forget to check it as valid if it finally works... ;-)

Comment: Hi @Vi100 unfortunately that did not work.. The first page just returns the function in console. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code is correct. Maybe there's a CrossSite request problem as you're manipulating pages from two different domains... Try to publish your code and test it on production, maybe there works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call window.open(...) you have to assign the result to a variable, then you can use it to manipulate the new window contents, and look for elements the same that you do with the current one.
Be aware that you'll have to wait for the new window to be loaded before searching for elements on it, so for your pourpose it's better to put that code into the onload callback:

```
var theNewWindow = window.open("https://www.youtube.com");
theNewWindow.onload = function() {
    theNewWindow.document.getElementById("masthead-search-term").value = 'team';
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I made these change but now I am receiving a "cannot set property "value" of null..

Comment: I made an functional example of this:

var entry = prompt("enter shortcut");
if (entry == "yt") {
var newWindow = window.open("https://www.youtube.com");
var update = newWindow.document.getElementById("masthead-search-term").value = "team"
}